# Manual geo code field in civicrm profile

Tags: profile, email, geocoding

We use profiles (https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/) for updating organisation information by the organisations himself. We also use geo fiels to map organisation on a map. Civicrm create automatically geo coördinates (Lng, Lat) from an address . Beacause this automatically geocode is not always the correct place or the organisation we will give the possibility to also give the geo-code (Lng, Lat) by himself. Adding Lng and Lat is no problem but how can we let change the manual_geo_code from 0 to 1 by the organisation. Is don't see this option in the profile fields (contacts).